# Firefox HTML5 Audio: Media resource could not be decoded (OnMediaSinkAudioError)

Tags: firefox, html5-audio

This issue is related to playing media in Firefox. While trying to stream audio after moving workstations, I get the following error in the console:

`Media resource [...] could not be decoded [...] NS_ERROR_DOM_MEDIA_MEDIASINK_ERR (0x806e000b) Details: OnMediaSinkAudioError`

In this case, it's not down to the website setup or contents of the audio stream, as they were working before.

Searching online for `OnMediaSinkAudioError` or `NS_ERROR_DOM_MEDIA_MEDIASINK_ERR` only seem to turn up with code commits or repositories for Firefox itself, so this doesn't appear to be a common problem.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It turns out that in this scenario, the error is quite misleading, since it is caused by a misconfiguration of the Windows audio output device.

After swapping my headphones from the rear audio ports to the front and restarting the workstation, everything worked fine. Restarting Firefox may have also been sufficient.

Answer (score 9):

I had the same problem more than once, this time after showing the Console (on Soundcloud) I saw the `NS_ERROR_DOM_MEDIA_MEDIASINK_ERR` error logged and googled it to find this SO question. What fixed this issue for me was the 1st solution at [drivereasy](https://www.drivereasy.com/knowledge/solved-failed-to-play-test-tone/) (restarting the Windows Audio service), without even restarting Windows or Firefox.

1. Hold Down **Windows** logo and press **R** key. A Run dialog box will pop up.
2. Type `services.msc` in the run box and click OK button.
3. In right Services Window, find **Windows Audio** from the “Name” list and right-click on it. Click Restart in the pop-up menu. Then the audio service will restart.

A cmd oneliner would be `net stop AudioSrv && net start AudioSrv`, run as Administrator.

Comment: This seems like a Firefox error code that emcomprises many suberrors. I'm receiving it relatively often causing a streaming audio to stop, but for me it's in macOS.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using *VS CODE Live Server* extension, Javascript Audio() won't play sound. Try running the site without the extension.

Comment: Yes, but will that extension cause the error reported by the OP?

Comment: I had the same issue too and I opened the file using Firefox normally and all audio worked, VSCode Firefox preview had a audio decoding error, so that fixed it! Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I was receiving the similar error `(Media Resource xxx could not be decoded.)` in `Firefox 46.0.1` and it turns out, the browser does not support .wav files, it worked fine with mp3 audio files.

I had to use embed element with `type="application/x-mplayer2"` which triggered vlc component to play the file. We were okay with this work around as we only use this website internally and had to stick to older version of `Firefox` for some reasons.

Though, the audio wav files worked fine in `Google Chrome` and `Mozilla Firefox` latest versions.